# Find such $\alpha$ and $\beta$, that $f(x)$ is differentiable for all  ∈ R

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  (x+\alpha)e^{-\beta x},  & x < 0,\\    
  \alpha x^{2}+\beta x +1,  & x \geq 0.   
\end{cases}
$$
How to find such $\alpha$ and $\beta$, that $f(x)$ is differentiable for all  ∈ R?
I tried to compute it via derivative limits form, but not quite sure in this approach. I decided to prove that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})}{h}$ does exist, and checked both limits on it. Maybe there is some another approaches, or mine is wrong?

Comment: Hint: due to limit properties, you know the derivative exists for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in both the upper piece and the lower piece. There is one point which is left out, though (which one?). Check the lateral limits to that point and impose equality

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable then it is also continuous, in particular it has to be continuous at $0$. From here you can find the value of $\alpha$ which is needed to find $\beta$.

And using the fact that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ you can find the value of $\beta$, i.e, by solving $\lim_{x\to0}=\frac{(x-\alpha)e^{-\beta x}-1}{x-0}=(\alpha x^2+\beta x+1)'_{x=0}$.